# In-order traversal of tree and apply given function to all nodes

Tags: .net, functional-programming, f#

I've written an in-order tree traversal function:

```
let rec inOrder (tree: BinTree<'a>) : 'a list =
    match tree with
    | Leaf -> []
    | Node(x,l,r) -> (inOrder l) @ [x] @ (inOrder r)
```

Now I want to use this function to 'map' over all the notes and apply a function that is given as a parameter. It should take a function and a tree and then return a tree. This is what I have so far:

```
let mapInOrder f t = 
    inOrder t
    |> Map.ofList
```

**For example, if I give the function this input:**

```
mapInOrder float (Node(1,Node(2,Leaf,Leaf),Node(3,Leaf,Leaf)));;
```

**I want the output:**

```
(Node(1.0,Node(2.0,Leaf,Leaf),Node(3.0,Leaf,Leaf)))
```

Answer (score 4):

To map a function over a `List` use the function `List.map`:

```
let mapInOrder f t = 
    inOrder t
    |> List.map f
```

But this function would produce a List as an output. Your example would produce:

```
[ 1.0 ; 2.0 ; 3.0 ]
```

To produce the output you expect instead your `mapInOrder` should traverse the tree producing another tree after applying the function to each element.

Comment: Yes, this is wher I'm stuck. So I should basically do a modified version of my inOrder function?

Comment: Exactly, if your output needs to be a tree then it is simply a `map` function for tree. It should be very similar to what you have in `inOrder` except that it also accepts the function `f` as a parameter and applies it to every element.

Comment: Hm could you maybe point me in the right direction? This is my idea so far `let rec mapInOrder f (t: BinTree<'a>) =
    match t with
    | Node(x,l,r) -> f(x) f(l) f(r)`

Comment: `Node(x, l, r) ->  Node(f x, mapInOrder f l, mapInOrder f r)`

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've come with:

```
type BinTree<'a> =
    | Leaf 
    | Node of x :'a  * l:BinTree<'a> * r:BinTree<'a>

let rec inOrder (tree: BinTree<'a>) : 'a list =
    match tree with
    | Leaf -> []
    | Node(x,l,r) -> (inOrder l) @ [x] @ (inOrder r)

let exampleTree = (Node(1,Node(2,Leaf,Leaf),Node(3,Leaf,Leaf)));;

let mapInOrder tree mapFunc = 
    tree
        |> inOrder 
        |> List.map mapFunc

let res = mapInOrder exampleTree double
//val res : double list = [2.0; 1.0; 3.0] <-------------- result of your current try

let rec copyAndMapInOrder<'b> (tree: BinTree<'a>) mapFunc : BinTree<'b> =
    match tree with
    | Leaf -> Leaf
    | Node(x,l,r) -> Node((mapFunc x), (copyAndMapInOrder l mapFunc), (copyAndMapInOrder r mapFunc))

let res2 = copyAndMapInOrder exampleTree double
//val res2 : BinTree<double> = Node (1.0,Node (2.0,Leaf,Leaf),Node (3.0,Leaf,Leaf)) <-- expected result
```

This code is just my implementation of what @AMieres suggests above.

Comment: Very good. Just one comment, I see you named the  function parameter `functor`. Actually, the type `BinTree` and the function `copyAndMapInOrder` together form a functor.A functor is a generic type and a mapping function.

Comment: @AMieres Thank you for the correction, what would be a better name for the mapping function in this case?

Comment: Since it is simply a function I usually just call it `f`.